# How in the most elegant way output unknown number

Tags: java

my method is getting one number and this number contains in [0, 1, 2]. And i am looking for the most elegant and straightforward way to get two others from this array. For now, I came up with that:

```
method(int number){
    int firstNumber = number;
    int secondNumber;
    int thirdNumber;
    List<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(0);
    rows.add(1);
    rows.add(2);
    rows.remove(Integer.valueOf(number));
    secondNumber = rows.remove(0);
    thirdNumber = rows.remove(0);
}
```

but this solution takes so many lines

Comment: Possibly a code-review stack exchange question

Comment: What should the method actually be doing? It's not returning anything.

Comment: What bothers me the most is thatall these lines do nothing useful at all. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: it's the piecie of something different, the piecie of something not important to know to answear this qestion

Comment: If you have a large number of elements and you quickly want to remove a few, you may want to check [`Set`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) too.

Comment: @Mateusz, please understand that we're all trying to help you here, and it's really important that questions include all relevant information. All of this is explained in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams.

```
public static List<Integer> method(int i) {
    return Stream.of(0, 1, 2).filter(j -> j != i).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To elaborate, since streams can be rather unreadable if you don't know what they're doing, Stream.of() creates a stream with the hardcoded values there, though it actually accepts varargs, so you can send an actual array. If you have a list, you can use List.stream().

.filter() accepts a function which should return a boolean. If it returns false, that particular value stays in the stream and is passed on to the next stage, if it returns true, it is filtered out (removed).

.collect() takes the stream and *collects* the values into, in this case, a List, though you can use Collectors.toSet() to get a Set, or write your own custom method to do return whatever you want.

Comment: looks smooth, thanks

Comment: Good answer. This actually explained to me what OP was _trying_ to do. You could improve this even more by adding some descriptions to the different steps that happen in this one-liner.

Comment: nice idea, alternatively one can also do `IntStream.of(0, 1, 2).filter(j -> j != i).toArray();`

Comment: thanks for the describe what streams are doing, but i know it so far. This year i did OCP exam and there was a lot of functional programing :)

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo to find the others:

```
public static void method(int number){
    int secondNumber = (number + 1) % 3;
    int thirdNumber = (number + 2) % 3;
    System.out.println(secondNumber);
    System.out.println(thirdNumber);
}
```

Comment: clever, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Another variant being:

```
List<Integer> source = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2));
source.removeIf(x -> x == number);
System.out.println(source);
```

but probably better to just do:

```
List<Integer> source = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2));
source.remove(Integer.valueOf(number));
```

to benefit from short-circuiting.